# Javascript select specificed data from html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is is possible for javascript to work like PHP to find specificed data with keyword ? for example

```
other html from html page
<video> <source type="application/x-mpegurl" src="https://xxxx.xxxx/xxx.mp4"></video>
other html from html page
```

How can javascript work 2 steps 1st get html page (like php CURL) 2nd find specificed data (in my case is all in src="xx") ("source type="application/x-mpegurl" is keywork for finding) ?

Sorry but I'm very bad in javascript.

Comment: Are you able to change the HTML code of that video? In that case, you should add an `id` attribute to the source tag (or the video tag)

Comment: @Alkitab Do you mean that you want to fetch the contents of a remote site with JavaScript and then fetch the requested data from the response? Or do you mean that you want the src attributes content from your very own page?

Comment: Step 1: you can't get anything from another site with javascript [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) and Step 2 has been asked and answered here lots of times, see [attribute equals](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: @HerrSerker I fetch data from another site. but I can use PHP to curl before to avoid origin policy

Comment: I suppose you use PHP then to fetch the data and do all the analysing stuff in PHP (and cache the result if possible). You can then get the result from your PHP by an AJAX call

Comment: @HerrSerker Yes it's a very good idea. Can you please give me example of javascript if I write PHP to output as JSON like {"source":"https://xxxx.xxx/xxx.mp4"}

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Fetching_data#Fetch (Under '3.') has an example with the fetch API. Fetch API is a fairly new technique. But there are serveral polyfills for fetch out there to support older browsers. Take Github fetch (whatwg) as an example: https://github.com/github/fetch/releases (file fetch.umd.js)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with javascript:

```
document.querySelector('source[type="application/x-mpegurl"]').src
```

Comment: This will only find the _first_ source on the page, No guarantee that that is the correct one

Comment: This is better, but it assumes that there is only one mpeg source on the page.

Comment: Yeap, but there is not explicitly stated that there can be multiple `application/x-mpegurl` sources in task, so no point to overengineer with cycles

Comment: OP says he's not good at JavaScript. He might not know about this

Comment: But it's not about JavaScript, it's about task/system he uses, if he don't know what/where/how many information he must find, he must start from there, not from writing a code. Anyway we can't ensure that even with cycles used we will find information he wants to, because source tag in his task have no unique data (we don't know is it), so what src we must return? First one? Last one? All of them?